# Qt-Application Deployment doesn't work. Missing entry point and dll's

Tags: c++, qt, dll, deployment, entry-point

In the last months I created a project with the Qt-Creator version 4.7.0, Qt version 5.11.1 (open source version).

Now I tried to deploy it following the [Qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment.html)  and building the project with MSVC2017-64bit compiler as well as running windeployqt.exe afterwards on the generated executable.

As I tried to run the executable after the programm finished copying the neccessary dlls into the folder, a warning appeared:

The entry point ?
eventFilter@QAbstractItemView@@MEAA_NPEAVQObject@@PEAVQEvent@@@Z wasn't found in DLL "my/project/path/releasefolder/project.exe".

It seems to me like something was wrong with the Qt-Objects I use in my project, but I couldn't find anything, as it still worked flawlessly in the Qt-Creator.

A thought it might be due to the compiler having issues, so I changed it to mingw32, which I also tried to deploy the same way. But somehow in this case the warning disappeared, but many dlls were still missing even though windeployqt.exe should've already done that. And I also couldn't find them anywhere on my hard drive. I also tried a third compiler, but the issues weren't going away.

I searched online and only found people having problems with an entry point missing in a Qt dll or missing the Qt-Dlls in general, but haven't found anything related to my case.

I also tried Dependency Walker on every executable, but it found even more missing dll, which led me to believe the executables were somehow currupted so I tried it again and again, but with no success unfortunately.

Has someone any idea, why that could happen, or any suggestion for me?
Maybe I should change something in my project, even though it works fine in the IDE. I just need a way to deploy my Qt project in any way.

EDIT: Build using the Desktop Kit in Qt Creator with MSVC2017 the described warning appeared.
Build with Mingw32 (Desktop Kit) and with MSVC2017 using the UWP Kit in Qt Creator the following Dll was missing, that I haven't found anywhere on my hard drive: MSVCP140_APP.dll

EDIT2: I ended up downloading the required dll, to somehow get it to work, but it still didn't work. One build, that required that dll now started but immediately closes itself again and the other build was suddenly warning me of a missing procedure entry point.

EDIT [SOLUTION]: I let the Qt Creator create a whole new fresh project and copied all files from my old project in the new one. After that I only copied all the dll files into the folder and it worked.

Comment: _You couldn't find them in your hard drive_ .. but your app still run in Creator! could you list some of those dll

Comment: If you can run in Creator, that means you are just missing files in deployment. windeployqt does suck and for my case i had to add 3 dlls to the folder before being able to run independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relying on windeploy, manually add the dll. I am assuming you have built the project using mingw. Assuming you are using Qt 5.11.1, go to 
C:\Qt\Qt5.11.1\5.11.1\\bin\ and copy all the dll files and paste in your executable folder. Also copy all directories from plugins folder (in /plugins) and paste in your folder. Now run the application, don't close the application. Now delete all the files from your executable folder. The one's not being used are deleted and the rest are left. I assume you are doing this on target computer. This might help.

Comment: Thanks, first of I tried creating a new project and copying all the files from the old project to the new one. Then I used your suggestion to copy every dll into the folder and deleting those not used.
I don't actually know what exactly solved the problem, but it worked out fine.